# Row merging in sql

Tags: sql

How to merge the duplicate records in single rows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need aggregation :

```
select id, max(lname) as lname, max(fname) as fname, max(address) as address,
       max(zip) as zip, max(city) as city, max(state) as state, max(phone)
from table t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id, max(lname) as lname, max(fname) as fname, max(address) as address,
       . . . 
from t
group by id;
```